# Почему я могу голосовать за переоткрытие своих вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, переоткрытие-вопросов

Недавно под своим закрытым вопросом я увидел кнопку «переоткрыть», нажал и [вопрос переоткрылся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1201761/timeline#history_bea59c67-53a7-4e43-94ab-b8bbbf965223). Мне кажется, что когда человек может голосовать за переоткрытие своего вопроса — это как-то неправильно.

Comment: Президенты же за избрание себя самого на выборах голосуют. Так чем мы хуже?

Comment: @avp действительно, что же тогда за свои посты нельзя голосовать ... очень странно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вряд ли кто откажется проголосовать за свой пост - и нафига бы нужны эти бесконечные единицы? К тому же голос за переоткрытие может привести к действию, тогда как посту какое-то действие не грозит...ну кроме удаления модератором (кстати, пофлагать свой пост тоже нельзя).

Comment: Да в конце-концов, вы взяли да изменили свой вопрос - и своим голосом инициируете процесс переоткрытия. А то вы можете его изменить, а никто и не заметит, что вы его исправили...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Объясню:

- Чтоб переоткрыть вопрос нужно 5 голосов — ваш голос был просто пятым ;)
- Если вы задали вопрос, его закрыли, то вы можете его отредактировать и он отправится в очередь проверок на переоткрытие. Но если он достаточно старый, то правки недостаточно — нужен голос за "переоткрыть" — именно для этого у вас есть такое право.